# Uploading range slider data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a music website that is PHP interactive in which a
user will be able to view an artists profile and rate them based on the
Attributes: Wordplay, Flow, Metaphors, and Charisma using a form with
range sliders.

I want it so that when the viewer is
adjusting the range sliders, the corresponding value will appear next to the slider. Then, when the viewer submits the form, I want the values to be entered in the database 'lr' into the table attributes which holds the columns "Wordplay","Flow", "Metaphors", and "Charisma" in INT format.

This is what I have so far. Could somebody help me out please?

---

profilepage.html.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="?submitattr" method="POST" style="display:block">
<label for=Wordplay>Wordplay: </label>
<input type=range min=50 max=100 value=75 step=1 id=fader>
<output for=fader class=value name=outputwordplay>75</output><br>
<label for=Flow>Flow: </label>
<input type=range min=50 max=100 value=75 step=1 id=fader1>
<output for=fader1 class=value name=outputflow>75</output><br>
<label for=Metaphors>Metaphors: </label>
<input type=range min=50 max=100 value=75 step=1 id=fader2>
<output for=fader2 class=value name=outputmetaphors>75</output><br>
<label for=Charisma>Charisma: </label>
<input type=range min=50 max=100 value=75 step=1 id=fader3>
<output for=fader3 class=value name=outputcharisma>75</output><br>
<input type=submit name=submit value=Submit> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

`
Index.php

```
<?php

     $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','xxxxx','xxxxx');


  if(isset($_POST['submitattr'])){

$wordplay = $_GET['outputwordplay'];
$flow = $_GET['outputflow'];
$metaphors = $_GET['outputmetaphors'];
$charisma = $_GET['outputcharisma'];




    $sql = "INSERT INTO attributes (Wordplay,Flow, Metaphors,Charisma) VALUES('$wordplay','$flow','$metaphors','$charisma')";

    $query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if(!$query){
        echo "Couldn't enter data";

    }
    else{
        echo "Data entered";
    }


}


       include 'profileuser.html.php';

?>
```

Comment: You're doing `?submitattr` in your action but using POST `if(isset($_POST['submitattr']))` - Same thing for the rest of your form elements. Do the reverse of that. Plus, you really should quote your form elements. I also don't get these `output`. Inputs are the ones that are usually named.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and JavaScript part should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('output[for=wordplay]').html($('#wordplay').val());
    $('#wordplay').bind('change', function () {
        $('output[for=wordplay]').html($('#wordplay').val());
    });

    $('output[for=flow]').html($('#flow').val());
    $('#flow').bind('change', function () {
        $('output[for=flow]').html($('#flow').val());
    });

    $('output[for=metaphors]').html($('#metaphors').val());
    $('#metaphors').bind('change', function () {
        $('output[for=metaphors]').html($('#metaphors').val());
    });

    $('output[for=charisma]').html($('#charisma').val());
    $('#charisma').bind('change', function () {
        $('output[for=charisma]').html($('#charisma').val());
    });
});
```

```html
 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="?submitattr">
    <label for="wordplay">Wordplay:
        <input type="range" name="wordplay" step="1" id="wordplay" min="0" max="100" />
        <output for="wordplay"></output>
    </label>
    <br />
    <label for="flow">Flow:
        <input type="range" name="flow" step="1" id="flow" min="0" max="100" />
        <output for="flow"></output>
    </label>
    <br />
    <label for="metaphors">Metaphors:
        <input type="range" name="metaphors" step="1" id="metaphors" min="0" max="100" />
        <output for="metaphors"></output>
    </label>
    <br />
    <label for="charisma">Charisma:
        <input type="range" name="charisma" step="1" id="charisma" min="0" max="100" />
        <output for="charisma"></output>
    </label>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In your PHP part you will have to change just a few lines:

```
$wordplay = $_POST['wordplay'];
$flow = $_POST['flow'];
$metaphors = $_POST['metaphors'];
$charisma = $_POST['charisma'];
```

First you have to use the post methode like you declared in your HTML. Also you have to get the value the input NOT of the output element.